# Python try except else invalid syntax?

Tags: if-statement, syntax, try-catch, except

So I am trying to set up a small script in Python's IDLE.  The IDLE syntax check tells me this code has a syntax error:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os
def ftpconnect(address, username, password):
    ftp_connection = 0
    ftp = FTP(address)
    try:
        ftp.login(username, password)
        print(ftp.getwelcome())
        if ftp.getwelcome() == '220 FTP Connected!':
            return 1
    else:
        return 0
print(ftpconnect('10.10.10.xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'))
```

The syntax error comes anywhere that I try to get out of the "try" statement, here being the "else:" line.  I've looked around and it seems like I have the right syntax...any thoughts?

Thanks!  I'm running Python 2, not 3.

Comment: Finally figured it out, see answer...

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with `try/else`? `else` makes now sense (and is invalid) unless it is preceded by an `except`.

Comment: Looking at this years later, you're totally right! I was totally missing an `except` statement there, that should have been my first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the problem with my syntax (missing except statement entirely), my ftp attempt statement was outside of the `try` block. Since I was not "try"ing it, it failed anyway.